# Why v-slider (Vuetify) has no width?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to create a v-slider, but just on default empty v-slider tag has no width or thumb align center:

[image: Image of strange slider]

This bold point is the thumb of slider and no one slider bar.

```html
<div v-if="typeList[0] === 'grade'" class="formItem__grade">
    <v-radio-group v-model="item.value" inline>
         <v-radio v-for="el in item.meta.answers" :label="el" :value="el" :disabled="disable"></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
    <!-- 
    <v-slider v-model:model-value="item.value"
        :ticks="item.meta.answers"
        :max="item.meta.answers.length"
        show-ticks="always"
        step="1"
        tick-size="3"
    ></v-slider>
    -->
    <v-slider></v-slider>
</div>
```

In the commented code, you can see that I tried to set props, but it did not work. So I tried `<v-slider>` without any props (as in the image), but it does not work either.

Comment: Try to give minimal code reproduction of issue you encounter. Any playground will help you with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when you don't wrap you Vuetify components into a `v-app`. It works when you do:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify} = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()
const App = {
  setup() {
    return {
      sliderVal1: ref(25),
      sliderVal2: ref(1), 
      item: {meta: {
        answers: ['a1', 'a2']
      }},
      isVapp: ref(true)
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<div id="app">

  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="isVapp"/> with v-app</label>
  
  <component :is="isVapp ? 'VApp' : 'div'">
    <div>
      <v-slider v-model="sliderVal1" />
    </div>
    {{sliderVal1}}
    <div>
      <v-slider
        v-model="sliderVal2" 
        :ticks="Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(item.meta.answers))" 
        :max="item.meta.answers.length - 1" 
        show-ticks="always" 
        step="1" 
        tick-size="3" 
        color="blue"
      />
    </div>

    {{sliderVal2}}
    
  </component>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's really works. But it so strange, I always used vuetify components without <v-app> and no problems are: <v-radio>, <v-text-field>, <v-table>, <v-select> etc.

Comment: Yeah, since adding `v-app` is usually done once during setup, I tend to forget that it is there. But since it provides basic configuration classes, like theming, it should always be used. Looking at the slider, the position of the knob depends on whether direction is left-to-right or right-to-left, whereas the default color of the slider bar depends on the theme class. Makes sense. And both is provided through `v-app`. Yay v-app, I guess...